# How to show the lead history in odoo 9?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-9

I am tring to show the lead history like below image .

[image]

but, i don't know how to show this . if you have any idea please share with me .

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line under the class name of yours.

```
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin', 'crm.tracking.mixin']
```

Then add the following option in your field `'track_visibility='onchange'`
So whenever the filed value is changed the history will be captured

Please look at the below sample

```
class Lead(FormatAddress, models.Model):
_name = "crm.lead"
_description = "Lead/Opportunity"
_order = "priority desc,date_action,id desc"
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin', 'utm.mixin']
_mail_mass_mailing = _('Leads / Opportunities')

#field declaration
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', track_visibility='onchange')
```

Comment: thanx@sfx for your reply , but this is also avilable in crm.lead . so by default  it would be show in the history , but it can't .

Comment: hii@sfx , The above functionality was workied till November 24 , but when i update the odoo , after that is was not worked . Have you any idea please share with me .

Comment: Did you change anything in the code? If yes please paste your code

Comment: hii@sfx , no , i didn't change anything . Also when i install odoo 9 in other laptop , so the same problem are also there . Is this facility available in odoo 9 now or not . I have a little doubt .